# Python multi layer web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, pycharm

I want to go through every URL on this list (https://express-press-release.net/Industries/Automotive-press-releases.php) and then copy data and get back to root list for the next one.
I can scrape from the single page but can't scrape through multiple links.

Comment: Hello Sohel, please provide more detail and clarity, or this question might be closed. Thank you.

Comment: Could you post some code, Sohel, to show what you've tried so far and why it has not worked?

Answer (score 1):

YOu can find all the `<a>` tags with href and pull those into a list. Then just iterate over that list. You may need to add some extra filters of some sort as you may only want specific links, but this will get you going:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://express-press-release.net/Industries/Automotive-press-releases.php'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)

root = 'https://express-press-release.net/'

link_list = [ root + a['href'] for a in links if '..' in a['href'] ]

for link in link_list:
    do some stuff...
```